# Nested IF statements, second IF Statement is not working

Tags: formula

I have nested IF statements, and the first IF statement is correctly returning "Yes" when a record type does not have all of the values present, but the second IF statement - written the same way  - does not seem to correctly return a YES. What could be wrong?

```
IF(
    AND(
        OR(
            Record_Type_Name__c = "Record Type 1",
            Record_Type_Name__c = "Record Type 2",
            Record_Type_Name__c = "Record Type 3",
            Record_Type_Name__c = "Record Type 4"
        ),
        OR(
            ISNULL(Number_of_Employees__c),
            ISNULL(TEXT(Industry__c)),
            ISNULL(Current_LPM__c),
            ISNULL(TEXT(Accepts_Online_Payments__c)),
            ISNULL(TEXT(Current_Payments_Solution__c))
        )
    ),
    "YES",
    IF(
        AND(
            OR(
                Record_Type_Name__c = "Record Type 5",
                Record_Type_Name__c = "Record Type 6",
                Record_Type_Name__c = "Record Type 7",
                Record_Type_Name__c = "Record Type 8"
            ),
            OR(
                ISNULL(TEXT(Industry__c)),
                ISNULL(Number_of_Employees__c)
            )
        ),
        "YES",
        "NO"
    )
)
```

Comment: Please include examples of input that give you the incorrect result. Also, below the area where you enter your formula, what option do you have selected for handling null/blank values (treat blanks as blanks, or treat blanks as zeros)?

Comment: The input I gave the formula was Record Type 5, Industry was null but No. of Employees was completed.  Options for handling null / blank values = treat blanks as blanks - where that is an option.

Comment: Like I said, it's an option that appears below the part of the screen where you would enter that formula (when you are editing what I assume is a formula field). Are you certain that `Industry__c` is null? That is, the automatic `--None--` option is selected when you go to edit the record, and not a similar-looking picklist value like `None` (without the two dashes on both sides). I'm assuming `Industry__c` is a picklist, but I'd like you to confirm or deny that.

Comment: Yes Industry is null, Yes it is a picklist field - the automatic "--None--" is the option selected

Comment: Also confirmed that the formula is treating blanks as blanks not as zeros

Comment: I'm about out of ideas at this point. The next step I'd take is to strip out the parts of the formula that you know work (i.e. the outermost `IF()`) and keep paring it down one thing at a time until you get a better idea of what is causing the issue. That, or start working from the bottom-up (start with `IF(OR(ISNULL(TEXT(Industry__c)), ISNULL(Number_of_Employees__c)), 'yes', 'no')`. Maybe try `ISBLANK()` instead of `ISNULL()`.

Comment: If you have just 8 record types, then you only need to check Industry / Number of Employees once, not twice.   IF( OR( ISBLANK(TEXT(Industry__c)), ISBLANK(Number_of_Employees__c) ), "Yes", IF([do your recordtype 1-4 logic here]) )

Comment: Instead of `ISNULL(TEXT(Industry__c))`, try `ISPICKVAL(Industry,"")` which is how I handle null picklists

Comment: I changed the formula from "ISNULL" to "ISBLANK" and it is now working

Answer (score 1):

Updated the formula to ISBLANK expressions and this solved the problem.